# How to assert identity in a secure and non-copyable way?

Tags: public-key, identity-based-encryption

Say I have the Mona Lisa, and I want to stick an RFID tag or similar mechanism on a back corner of the painting to verify this is the real Mona Lisa and any others are forgeries.  What mechanism would you use so that an inspector could challenge the tag and verify it is the original tag, and how do you prevent simply copying the tag response and writing to another RFID, creating another "genuine" article?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. Is this the real case of your application? Then sorry it will fail miserably. This tag cannot be part of the paint. If you want it to be part of it, you need to include some information about the painting that the replicas don't have. This can be a close-up picture from a corner...

Comment: the idea is to tag an item in a way that it can be verified authentic.  An alternative way to think about it would be how would be how to identify a device as unique and not a duplicate given some public knowledge of the device?  My instinct tells me this is impossible.  My limited knowledge of public-private key communication makes me think I'm missing something though.

Comment: If you don't be specific the answer will not satisfy you. For example, there are Physically Unclonable Function that helps us to identify deceives like CD's FPGA, CCD's

Comment: You can sure make a tag authenticate itself using a MAC / signature within a challenge / response protocol. However, as indicated, that authenticates the tag, but not the Mona Lisa.

Comment: kelalaka, thank you for the info, I will look into the physically unclonable function.

Comment: Maarten, thank you.  Is there a standard protocol or something I can investigate for this type of challenge/response?  My goal is to physically embed the tag so tampering would be obvious.